# Android save screenshot

Tags: android

i trying to do an application to take screenshot for android tablet every 1 second and view the image in desktop application. i got a help to do it but it takes the screenshot for my app only . what i need is to take screenshot even the user minimize the application so in the desktop application it will keep tracking what the user is doing on the tablet.

appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: The system can do it, but I'm not sure this is possible for 3rd-party apps (likely for security reasons). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android -- You can make screenshots from inside an app, but the apps that can take a screenshot anytime/anywhere usually require root and are probably doing something not provided by the public API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [android-screenshot-library](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/wiki/Usage), which should work without a root access; however it still have some limitations

Also [AndroSS](https://github.com/tstein/AndroSS) is another option for Tegra-based Android phones